# How to load dependencies and subfolders in Pycharm?

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, relative-path

I am so new with python and pycharm and i got confuse!!
When I run my project in pycharm it gives me an error about not finding the path of my file. The physical file path is:

```
'../Project/BC/RequiredFiles/resources/a_reqs.csv'
```

My project working directory is "Project/BC" and the project running file (startApp.sh) is there too. but the .py file that wants to work with a_req.csv is inside the "RequiredFiles" folder. There is the following code in the .py file:

```
reqsfile = os.getcwd() + "/resources/a_reqs.csv"
```

it returns: `'../Project/BC/resources/a_reqs.csv'`

instead of: `'../Project/BC/resources/RequiredFiles/a_reqs.csv'`

while the .py file is in `"RequiredFiles"` the `os.getcwd()` must include it too. but it does not.

The problem is that i can not change the addressing code. because this code works in another IDE and other people who work with the code in other platform or OS do not have any problem. I am working in mac OS and if i am not mistaken the code works with windows!!

So, how can i tell Pycharm (in mac) to see and load "RequiredFiles" folder as the subfolder of my working directory!!!

Answer (score 1):

`os.getcwd` returns the current working directory of the process (which may be the directory where `startApp.sh` is located or another one, depending on the PyCharm's run configuration setting, or, if you start the program from the command line, the directory in which you execute the command).

To make a path independent on the current working directory, you can take the directory where your Python file is located and build the path from it:

```
os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/resources/a_reqs.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I see is:

```
reqsfile = os.getcwd() + "/resources/a_reqs.csv"
```

Which produces: "../Project/BC/resources/a_reqs.csv", whereas your desired output is 
"../Project/BC/resources/RequiredFiles/a_reqs.csv". Since we know os.getcwd is returning "/Project/BC/", then to get your desired result you should be doing:

```
reqsfile = os.getcwd() + "/resources/RequiredFiles/a_reqs.csv"
```

But since you want the solution to work with or without the `RequiredFiles` subdirectory you could apply a conditional solution, ie something like:

```
import os.path
if os.path.exists(os.getcwd() + "/resources/RequiredFiles/a_reqs.csv"):
    reqsfile = os.getcwd() + "/resources/RequiredFiles/a_reqs.csv"
else:
    reqsfile = os.getcwd() + "/resources/a_reqs.csv"
```

This solution will set the reqsfile to the csv in the RequiredFiles directory if the directory exists, and thus will work for you. On the other-hand, if the RequiredFiles directory doesn't exist, it will default to the csv in /resources/.
Typically when groups collaborate on projects, the maintain the same file hierarchy so that these types of issues are avoided, so you might want to consider moving the csv from /RequiredFiles/ to /resources/.